# How to set minDate 2

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I want to highlight date day after tomorrow date,I am using following code but not working fine.

```js
$('#date').datetimepicker({
  timepicker: false,
  format: 'Y-m-d',
  formatDate: 'Y-m-d',
  minDate: 2,
  scrollDay: false,
  scrollMonth: false,
  scrollYear: false
});
```

Comment: Can you share the plugin site documentation link?

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the minDate value as a Date object

```js
var date = new Date(); // get current date
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2); // add two days to it
$('#date').datetimepicker({
  timepicker: false,
  format: 'Y-m-d',
  formatDate: 'Y-m-d',
  minDate: date,
  scrollDay: false,
  scrollMonth: false,
  scrollYear: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="date" />
```

---

Or as in [the documentation set `'+1970/01/03'`](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#mindate) for  min date to day after tomorrow

```js
$('#date').datetimepicker({
  timepicker: false,
  format: 'Y-m-d',
  formatDate: 'Y-m-d',
  minDate: '+1970/01/03',
  scrollDay: false,
  scrollMonth: false,
  scrollYear: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="date" />
```